# Photo management software with facial recognition

Tags: windows, photography, facial-recognition

I need a photo management software that lets me load a lot of photos or different people, pets, and places and it does smart categorization of them based on facial recognition.

Like Google Photos but offline.

Requirements:

- Photos management
- Facial recognition

Optional:

- Identify and eliminate duplicate pics
- Editing capability might be nice but is not required
- Ability to give specific users ability to view (reasonable security goes without saying)
- Intuitive tagging

OS: Windows. License: Any

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to take look at Tonfotos: https://tonfotos.com/ It has both free and paid versions, has face recognition, displays photo location on the map, has timeline view and all other stuff you would expect from photo management applications, including duplicates detection.

However, one of your requirements does not make sense to me: "Ability to give specific users ability to view". I'm afraid this is not something you would expect from desktop application (your requirement is Windows, right?) Desktop applications are not servers, they run on your desktop. If you want to this library to be exposed to the web (with reasonable security), then you should be looking into either cloud services (like Google Photos), or self-hosted applications services like Photoprism: https://photoprism.app/ But again, you will need a dedicated server (linux-based) for it to run on. It is not for your Windows desktop.